# How to declare the type of a setter in JavaScript/VSCode/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have a very simple example, to demonstrate the issue:

```js
class Person {
    _name = '';
    _age  = 0;
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    /**
     * @type {string}
     */
    set name(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
    /**
     * @type {number | string}
     */
    set age(age) {
        if (age === 'too old') {
            age = 100000;
        }
        this._age = age;
    }
}
```

I use VSCode to do typechecking, but why does it fail on the type?

I explicitly say that the age setter can take either a number or a string:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the type but instead wrote a JSDoc comment. That doesn't actually affect your code. Thus TypeScript implicitly sets the type `number`.

If you want the setter to accept both `string` and `number` one solution would be to use a union type like this:

```
set age(age: string | number) {
   ...
}
```

Keep in mind that you get problems when setting `this._age` later on because `this._age` also implicitly has the type `number` (default value `0`) and therefore cannot be assigned a value of type `string | number`.

Comment: It is not typescript. JSDoc is used to have hints in code. VSCode will know the potential type of the variable and will activate all required features, like autocompletion.

Comment: JSDoc cannot override your typescript code. This is not a simple autocompletion problem but a typescript error. Also if this is not typescript code why is the question tagged as such.

Comment: @Behemoth It is tagged as TypeScript because VSCode is using TypeScript to type-check JavaScript with JSDoc annotations.

Comment: That's a valid argument. Does my answer help you with your problem in any way? If not, I'll delete this because it would be out of context.

Comment: @Behemoth Yea, it helps to point out that this is exactly not what I'm asking for, so it reduces the confusion of what this question is about. Thank you for your answer, @Behemoth!

Comment: Are you expecting that the JSDoc type overrides the typescript type, at least for your IDE? JSDoc doesn't help VSCode type checking. It's just extra information.

Comment: @Behemoth Sorry, but you don't know what you are talking about, TypeScript does all the inference from JSDoc annotations:
/** @type {'Behemoth'} */
var x;
Check this file for `JSDoc`: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/main/src/compiler/checker.ts

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to wrap your union types in parenthesise to be valid in JSDoc:

```
/**
* @type {(number | string)}
*/
```

From the [documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html):

> Multiple types (type union) This can be a number or a
> boolean.{(number|boolean)} This means a value can have one of several
> types, with the entire list of types enclosed in parentheses and
> separated by |.

Comment: Thank you, I tested, but it doesn't work with parenthesis either.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should work. Just check the type of `age` with `typeof` to narrow the type into an `if` statement.

```js
class Person {
  _name = '';
  _age  = 0;
  get name() {
      return this._name;
  }
  /**
   * @param {string} name
   */
  set name(name) {
      this._name = name;
  }
  get age() {
      return this._age;
  }
  /**
   * @param {number | string} age
   */
  set age(age) {
      if (typeof age === 'string') {
        if (age === 'too old') {
          age = 100000;
        } else {
          age = parseInt(age)
        }
      }
      this._age = age;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what did you test it with? In VSCode it still tells me its just a number, if you hover over it. And this creates an error too: const person = new Person; person.age = "too old";

Comment: Weird. I'm testing on VSCode and it works. What's the Typescript version you're at? I'm at 4.7.4

Comment: I tested on 4.7.4 and 4.8.0-beta, both fail: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDWgH00wBbeaAXmgHIaBuPAwsAcwqugAZH9p2ALtBLkAFAEosTAjMTwBAV0QYBACwCWEAHTEy8XgQC+0gPQAqM9OhnoAAQAOYRGSwQBidWlaHheq2ZNpCHlfMRF4SRw+GWg1TR1wznCDaGM+QWg2eAkpaNl5JRUNbRZ2FLSCc0tomwcnF0w0BVIAIyRoAB9oNw8vHyz-QL5goSzRLMirGXUAM2hRAQBPe3gUOayqSmoaHs9WGkm8mNn5ja3tgRQUaBQQABMD3JjnzPZOAEYuL6+Ul594EDBJ4vGRnaCOZDwACSaAE43Y4imMQqzxRMTiJTBWXKeDSwHQbnBSFQGGoaHgAHc4MT0LwVsh0FowQAiS7XW53Zn0IA

Comment: Is the file with `.js` extension? Because if it's `.ts` it's going to show this error like `typescriptlang.org/play` is doing.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! I created a new file and gave it the TS extension. Now the only problem is that JSDoc expects `@type` for getters/setters and not `@param`, even though this is what TypeScript needs.

Comment: Nice to know! I'll appreciate (and other users too with the same issue) if you accept the answer

Comment: Thank you @lepsch, the issue is that it still doesn't work in JSDoc, you can hover over "age" and see that it is only a "number" and JSDoc doesn't support `@param` for setters/getters. So this is not exactly the solution.

Comment: [Check out my IDE](https://imgur.com/S3gZfPT). `age` is properly parsed as `string | number`. It looks like your IDE and/or project is misconfigured somehow.